# Adding System Folders to This PC on Windows 11

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, files-folders

I just reset my computer to attempt to fix another unrelated issue, and the Desktop, Downloads, Documents, Pictures, Music, and Videos folders were removed from This PC where they had previously appeared in a section above the drives section . Now they are only visible on the File Explorer sidebar. Is there a way I can restore them to where they were?

I have searched online, but there doesn't seem to be any existing answers for this.

[Edit: This is where I want the folders to appear; they are already visible in the sidebar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvDi2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just because they are not visible in explorer does not mean that they were removed from the PC.

Try

- Open Explorer
- Click on **View** menu
- Click on **Panes**
- Click on **Navigation panes**
- Tick **Navigation pane**

Comment: They are still visible in explorer, just not in the "This PC" page. I can access them normally using the navigation sidebar.

Comment: Try (Windows File Explorer),  View, Show, and Select Navigation Pane.  That is similar to the answer given but a bit different.

Comment: I have already done that and can view the folders. I posted a screenshot showing where I want the folders to appear.

Comment: I know you did a reset, but something must have gone wrong. Try a Repair Install and Keep Everything.  That may correct the issue.    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11